# Laptop Power Supply Modification

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, voltage

I have an old laptop which I no longer have the charger for. I ordered a new charger for the same laptop series, but the plug is too large, and it is unlikely that I will find the same adapter (Acer is difficult with their proprietary plugs).

I have an idea to connect the power supply directly to the laptop. 
15.2V is the battery voltage. The charger provides an output of 19V at 3.42A.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Laptop model: Acer Aspire V3-371-558L

Comment: Title is slightly inaccurate. It's more whether it is possible to switch out the power supply of the laptop from a battery to a power supply, akin to a desktop, which are non-portable but function off wall power.

Comment: Title has been changed, this one should be more accurate.

Comment: That is better, but it is still unclear. You say "*connect the power supply directly to the laptop*", then mention battery voltage and charger voltage. You are not clear on how you intend to connect the power supply nor what its power ratings are.

Comment: The exact model would also help to clarify how it deals with the battery being absent and how the built-in power supply or distribution is handled to see if it would tolerate your transformer.  An even more important question is whether that new power supply is switching, which is the main characteristic of computer power supplies and increases their price threefold.  If it's not a switching PS, you should just forget about the whole question as you'll ruin your computer with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it, as it's far easier to purchase one of these http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0144DCH68 - I guarantee it will have an adapter to fit - they can easily be changed over on a charger like this.

Comment: Yep, I agree buying one of the chargers that have all of the ends will solve the problem. All in all, I think the asker made a simple mistake of not being sure what they ordered was the right one. It's kind of annoying that they have so many different sizes for the chargers.

Comment: It's the reason I learnt to solder. Vast majority of chargers are 19v 3.24a and are completely interchangeable.

Comment: Looks like a very useful product! I asked this question on the electric engineering community, and they recommend against doing so due to power management and voltage stabilizing. I'll probably go for your universal charger solution.